Is there a coherent notion of "weak orthogonality" of functions/distributions?
Recently I gave an answer to Laplace transforms of non-exponential, non-sinusoidal functions that claims the following:

Our [change-of-basis] interpretation doesn't quite survive [the generalization from Fourier transform to Laplace transform] intact. We've mapped our initial half-line function to a function on all of ℂ2 - so, we have a "weight" for each point of ℂ2, each corresponding to a complex exponential. But the space spanned by complex exponentials is not the half-line space that we originally started with, and we can't naively add these complex exponentials back up to obtain our original function. Heuristically, the Laplace "basis" lacks the orthogonality of the pure sinusoids - so the reasoning that justified the "decomposition" interpretation in the earlier cases falls apart.

I've been thinking about Laplace transforms for a while, and while I find the above answer compelling, it still feels incomplete.  We lose orthogonality of the "basis functions" when we generalize from Fourier space to Laplace space - do we retain anything weaker?
I don't know exactly how to attack this question formally, because there are a number of technical difficulties to talking about "orthogonality" even in the simpler Fourier case, despite the ubiquity and utility of the metaphor.  The discrete Fourier transform and Fourier series both involve function spaces on which an appropriate inner product is clearly available.
But the Fourier transform is not so fortunate; the inner product of two sinusoids over all of $\mathbb{R}$ is either not defined or infinite.  We can still see an "echo" of orthogonality if we squint, though, because an oscillating integral is qualitatively very different from - and, intuitively, of negligible magnitude in comparison to - a divergent integral.  Similarly, it seems difficult to technically describe the set of delta distributions as "orthogonal" - but the form is still there.
In the Laplace case, as mentioned above, we do not have orthogonality even if we squint - there is clear "cross-talk" between the different "basis functions" where the inner product is well-defined.  However, again from my earlier answer:

The interpretation doesn't disappear entirely, though - we can still think of the inversion formula as "adding up" (using contour integration) the infinitesimal contribution of each "basis" function along a line in complex space that spans the entire (imaginary) frequency spectrum.

Considering all this: can we recover a "weaker" notion of orthogonality that continues the metaphor of a basis rigorously into the full Fourier space?  Can this be used to describe, e.g., why the Laplace inversion formula seems to "take information" only by spanning the imaginary spectrum, while variation along the real axis seems to cancel itself out?
More generally, is there an analog to the "orthogonality" constraint on the eigenvectors of a finite-dimensional Hermitian matrix, when we generalize to the infinite-dimensional case?
